# How to define your own list of invokables and access this from a AbstractFactory

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to build my own list of invokables and access it from my AbstractFactory.

```
/**
 * Get the service config
 */
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
        ),
        'foo-invokables' => array(
            'FooService' => 'Foo\Service\FooService',
         )
    );
}
```

The factory should then check this list to see the alias is within the list of foo-invokables.

```
public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $objServiceManager, $sCanonicalName, $sRequestedName) {
    // TODO check if the $sRequestedName is contained with in the foo-invokables return true
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the 'request name' is already within the 'invokables' config then you should never even get to the `AbstractFactory`. The service manager will only use the abstract factory as a fall back if it cannot find any registered service with that name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as simple as this:

```
class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface //...
{

    //...

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'my_invokables' => [
                'MyInvokables\Invokable1',
                'MyInvokables\Invokable2',
            ]
        ];
    }

    //...

}

class AbstractMyInvokablesFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        return in_array($requestedName, $config['my_invokables']);
    }

    //...
}
```